# Storing pdf in Pouch db using angular ngStorage

Tags: pdf, local-storage, ng-storage

I am new at `Pouch DB` is there a way to save a `.pdf` on `Pouch` using ngStorage or pure js?
I can't find a code snippet for files that are not `json`.
Searching for a way lead me to [json in local storage](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/12/use-ngstorage-angularjs-local-storage-needs/).
Can somone provied a code snippet or any help on how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read the Pouch DB API docs?

[create/update](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#create_document)  a doc

Comment: You definitely need some front end technology to handle the upload like [PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp). Then you can run a PHP script to insert into your DB. If you do not want PHP, you may want to have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)